# Trying to pull out certain numbers from a string

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I have a string of numbers which looks like this

```
 ["100000100685716-2","603834770-2", "604544970-3"]
```

can someone help me with a regular expression to match each long (first number before the "-") so i can add it to an array?

Comment: Yes, _someone_ can help you. Please show what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: why would you use regex when it looks like `str.split("-")[0]` would work? (and `Long.parseLong()`)

Comment: What you posted looks like an array of string.  Is that supposed to be your output?

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys, I've found what i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex should work: `(\d+)-`

Comment: This answer will pick up the "-" in the string also, I don't believe he wants the "-" sign.

Comment: @IronWilliamCash That's the point of the parentheses; only the digits will be captured.

Comment: hmmm, my regex app is picking up the "-" also... weird

Comment: @IronWilliamCash that regex will match the `-`, but it should also create a group that only has the `\d+` in it

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a regex here:

- Use `int pos = str.indexOf('-')` to get the location of the dash
- Use `str.substring(0, pos)` to get the initial portion of the string.

If dashes in the input strings are optional, you would need to add a check of `pos` to be non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:\"\d+)
```

This should do exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "[\"100000100685716-2\",\"603834770-2\", \"604544970-3\"]";
System.out.println(s.split("-")[0].substring(2));
```